# How to solve breakpoint error in xcode?

Tags: ios

I am getting a thread error Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1 in my IBAction function. The code runs without error, but when I click the button on the simulator, the simulator crashes and produces the breakpoint error.

Comment: you connected the action(delegate) to the button ?

Comment: Have you just set a breakpoint?  Look for a blue flag in the margin. Click it to turn it off or drag it out to delete it

Answer (score 0):

Connect your button to action as :[image]